# Azure DevOps show build warning total count

Tags: build, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Currently when looking at the summary page of a build pipeline in Azure DevOps I can only see up to 11 warnings per project. Is there a way to show the total count of warnings? I don't need to see what the warnings are, just a count of the total number of warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the max count is 11 on your side, because it can display 14 warnings here:

[image]

*I'm afraid you may need double check whether 11 is the actual total count for that pipeline.*

---

Anyway, you have another way, check its actual number programmatically. Just run below scripts from the `powershell terminal` in your local machine:

```
$token = "{token}"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_build/results?buildId={the build id you want to check}&__rt=fps&__ver=2"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get

Write-Host "results = $($response.fps.dataProviders.data.'ms.vss-build-web.run-details-data-provider'.issues.Count| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

[image]